# Setting a variable equal to a row number

Tags: excel, vba

I need to set EndOfFile and DataRange = to the row number they reside in.

Thanks in advance,

Scott

```
Dim NumOfRows As Integer
    Dim EndOfFile As Range
    Dim DataRange As Range 

Sub Find_xy_data()
    Dim RowArray(1 To 10000) As Range

    'Counters
    i = 2


       ' Locate last line of KLARF location data
    Cells.Find(What:="EndOfFile;", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Set EndOfFile = ActiveCell.Rows



    ' Locate first line of KLARF location data
    Cells.Find(What:="DefectRecordSpec", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
       Set DataRange = ActiveCell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Sub Find_xy_data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set the worksheet above, amend as required

    Dim EndOfFile As Range
    Dim DataRange As Range

    Set EndOfFile = ws.Cells.Find(What:="EndOfFile;")
    'find and set variable to range at which it was found
    Set DataRange = ws.Cells.Find(What:="DefectRecordSpec")
    If Not EndOfFile Is Nothing Then MsgBox "EndOfFile found at row " & EndOfFile.Row
    'if variable is not empty then found, prompt with msgbox
    If Not DataRange Is Nothing Then MsgBox "DefectRecordSpec found at row " & DataRange.Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the cell.
You can't return the row number or activate the cell if it's not found; an error will occur.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim EndOfFile As Range

    Set EndOfFile = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What:="EndOfFile;", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not EndOfFile Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox EndOfFile.Address & " is on row " & EndOfFile.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I won't have a chance to work on this until later but I wanted to say it's much appreciated.